# Javascript: after loading a page, is there any way to inhibit the use of a .js file loaded using the browser?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

after loading a page, is there any way to inhibit the use of a .js? I mean using any tool (firebug for example) in Firefox .

Regards

Javi

Comment: [NoScript?](http://noscript.net/) Why do you want to know? Any programming related thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's element inspector can stop and pause scripts. Is that what you mean?